# MySQL upgrade to 8.0 deleted my old data?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysqlupgrade

After installing MySQL 8, it started the server automatically and when I opened up MySQL Workbench, my tables were gone.

It says in the doc to start the server like so after installing it:

> mysqld_safe --user=mysql --datadir=/path/to/existing-datadir &

However, I did not take note of the datadir path of my previous installation and as I said, the server automatically started once the installation was done, so I could not run this command.

How can I run the `mysqld_safe` and specify my old data? Where is my old data?

Comment: Where is your *new* data? (`SELECT @@datadir`)

Comment: This might be my new data, but I want my old data back...By old data I simply mean the data that I had before upgrading to 8.0.

Comment: Alright... May I ask what your operating system is?

Comment: I mean, we can't tell you the exact directory in your PC where your data is because we don't have remote access to your hard disc drive. If it isn't possible to gather diagnostic information then this question is basically unanswerable.

Comment: Well, like everything I think it might be more nuanced. Maybe MySQL moves the old data to a specific location when going through the upgrade process? Maybe MySQL deletes the data if you don't open the new server version with the right datadir path? Maybe my datadir hasn't changed, but for some reason the tables aren't indexed yet in the new MySQL version? :)